# Can sequence of writing in Asterisk configuration affects the performance of VoIP?

Tags: configuration, sequence, voip, asterisk

guys! I have configuration like this in my extensions.conf

```
[globals]
[general]
autofallthrough=yes
[lain-lain]
[telpun]
exten => 1000,1,Dial(SIP/tes)
exten => 1001,1,Dial(SIP/tesku)
exten => 1002,1,Dial(SIP/1002)
exten => 1003,1,Dial(SIP/1003)
exten => 1004,1,Dial(SIP/1004)
exten => 1005,1,Dial(SIP/1005)
exten => 55,1,Playback(demo-echotest) ; Let them know what’s going on
exten => 55,2,Echo ; Do the echo test
exten => 55,3,Playback(demo-echodone) ; Let them know it’s over
```

if I change the order become like this :

```
[globals]
[general]
autofallthrough=yes
[lain-lain]
[telpun]
exten => 55,1,Playback(demo-echotest) ; Let them know what’s going on
exten => 55,2,Echo ; Do the echo test
exten => 55,3,Playback(demo-echodone) ; Let them know it’s over
exten => 1000,1,Dial(SIP/tes)
exten => 1001,1,Dial(SIP/tesku)
exten => 1002,1,Dial(SIP/1002)
exten => 1003,1,Dial(SIP/1003)
exten => 1004,1,Dial(SIP/1004)
exten => 1005,1,Dial(SIP/1005)
```

I wonder, what is the differences according the performance of voip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These files are parsed and loaded into memory at startup or when you reload the extensions.  The order they appear in the extensions.conf file shouldn't make a difference at all.